# environment settings in my django app are set to debug false but in production it acts as if its true

Tags: python, django, development-environment, production-environment

I have local and production settings for my django app that import from base like so

```
from .base import *

try:
    from .local import *
except:
    pass

try:
    from .production import *
except:
    pass
```

and in my base I have

```
import os
import dj_database_url
from .my_pass import SECRET, EMAIL_PASSWORD, EMAIL_USER

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))



SECRET_KEY = SECRET

DEBUG = False
```

and in my local

```
import os
import dj_database_url
from .my_pass import SECRET

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))


SECRET_KEY = SECRET

DEBUG = True
```

and in my production

```
from django.conf import settings

if not settings.DEBUG:
    import os
    import dj_database_url


    # Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
    PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))




    SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']

    DEBUG = False
```

But when I tested it out in production by doing this

example.com/jnxejnn

it showed me a list of urls as if DEBUG was set to true. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the order of the settings file:

- first it imports from base: DEBUG is False
- then it imports from local: DEBUG is True
- then it imports from production: at this point, DEBUG is True, so your `if not settings.DEBUG:` block is never entered, and DEBUG is not set to False again.

Thus, DEBUG remains True, as it is set in the local settings file.

I'm not sure what the purpose of your `if not settings.DEBUG` check is, but I think if you eliminate that condition, it will work as you expect.

[Edit]
Though the above did answer your question of "Why is that?", it doesn't really help meet your needs, so I'd recommend making a modification to your settings file like so:

```
from .base import *

if os.environ['DJANGO_SERVER_TYPE'] == 'local':
    try:
        from .local import *
    except:
        pass

if os.environ['DJANGO_SERVER_TYPE'] == 'production':
    try:
        from .production import *
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: if I remove that block then my local development won't behave as true and I cant debug. I'm following a tutorial. The point I even did this is so I won't have to manually change Default true/false everytime I git push heroku master

Comment: I'm not sure what tutorial you're working off of, but the way you're going about it necessarily leads to this condition.

Generally, you would use an environment variable to determine which settings file to load. See the edit to my answer for what I mean. Then, to indicate which settings file should be used, just set the `DJANGO_SERVER_TYPE` environment variable appropriately.

Comment: and remove the if settings.debug in production.py ?

Comment: Right, because we've placed the conditions in the settings file itself, you no longer need the condition in production.py

Comment: it's still gettingit's information from production. If I comment production out then it wil get the other settings

Comment: double check for you @Joseph

Comment: ultimately I did this and it worked it's a variation of yours because I don't know how to add local environment variables and believed me I tried I had to make it elif or it wouldnt work     'from .my_pass import LOCAL
from .base import *

if LOCAL == 'local':
    try:
        from .local import *
    except:
        pass

elif os.environ['DJANGO_SERVER_TYPE'] == 'production':
    try:
        from .production import *
    except:
        pass'

Comment: @nothingness For UNIX-y systems, you create environment variables in your shell, e.g, `export DJANGO_SERVER_TYPE=production`. You can view your environment with the `env` command.

Answer (score 0):

ultimately this is what worked for me

```
from .base import *

if os.getenv('_system_name') == 'OSX':
    from .local import *

else:
    from .production import *
```

I don't understand why tutorials make this so complicated. I ran printenv to look at the variables I was creating and try to understand why they weren't working. I noticed

```
_system_name=OSX
```

and thought I could use this because hopefully heroku didn't have the same name for their server

at the same time in one of my chrome tabs(I had multiple tabs open looking for an answer) I looked at a post on how to use environment variables because this

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SERVER_TYPE'] == 'production'
```

kept giving me this error

```
File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/src/gettingstarted/settings/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
if os.environ['DJANGO_SERVER_TYPE'] == 'local':
File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/bin/../lib/python3.5/os.py", line 683, in __getitem__
raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'DJANGO_SERVER_TYPE'
```

so I saw someone using this

```
os.getenv('TAG')
```

and figured I could use it like this

```
os.getenv('_system_name') == 'OSX'
```

and now my local works as it's supposed to and my production works as it's supposed to. I was currently trying to get this to work

```
from .base import *
try:
    from .local import *
except:
    pass

try:
    from .production import *
except:
    pass
```

which I have been seeking advice on and have been trying to make work for the last 3 days. If my solution isn't proper please let me know why it isn't. but as of right now it's working